# how to use count when joining two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables 
First Table tblHostel it contains three field like that
HostelName, RoomId, Capacity and content is like that

> HostelName RoomId  Capacity
>   Vivakanand 1-1 2
>   Vivakanand 1-2 1
>   Vivakanand 1-3 3

And second table is tblStudent having three field UserId,RoomId,HostelName and Data is like that

> HostelName   RoomId     UserId
>   Vivakanand    1-1         101
>   Vivakanand    1-1         102
>   Vivakanand    1-3         103

I want to merge these two tables in such a way I find the following type of out-put

> HostelName   RoomId     Capacity    Count
>   Vivakanand   1-1          2          2
>   Vivakanand   1-3          3          1

the count table counts room-id  in tblStudent.
For individual table I find that output by following command
`select RoomId,HostelName,count(RoomId) from tblStudent group by Roomid,Hostel;`

But how I merge these two tables to achieve the desire output,I also use join but I can't achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first join the tables based on the HostelName and RoomID, and then use `COUNT` function to get the count of students per room, like so:

```
select h.hostelname, h.roomid, h.capacity, count(s.userid) Count
from tblhostel h 
inner join tblstudent s on h.hostelname = s.hostelname 
and h.roomid = s.roomid
group by h.hostelname, h.roomid, h.capacity
```